# Monitoring Battery voltage using ESP8266 thinig dev board?

Tags: arduino, power, esp8266

I have ESP8266 thing dev board. I am trying to measure battery voltage and send it to ThingSpeak. I have two questions:
1) DO I need a voltage divider connected ?
2) I googled but couldn't exactly find any example which could help me how to code in order to get battery voltage using esp8266 thing dev board?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!!

Comment: Which battery are you monitoring? how are they connected? what is the battery voltage? can you share the setup and schematics of your circuit?  The device has ADC pin which you can connect to. sahre the battery details

Comment: I am using 4 AA batteries. Total voltage right now is about 5.40 V. Positive end is connected to VIN and negative end in the GND port of esp8266 thing dev board. Yes the board does have an ADC. But my question is what lines of code would give me voltage of battery? And how to wire ADC port ? Thank You!!

Comment: do you have datasheet of the dev board? you have to ask code(for review) in arduino forum

Answer (score 2):

> To read external voltage applied to ADC pin, use analogRead(A0). Input
>   voltage range is 0 — 1.0V.

Source: http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/reference.html

1. Depending on voltage of the battery, you can build a simple voltage divider to convert 0 to V volts of battery to 0 to 1 V.
2. If power has to be saved, a high side switch can be used to measure battery voltage only when needed

   ---

One example way of connecting the battery to ADC pin. Vin can be the battery point and Vout can be connected to a voltage divider. This will help to save power by not wasting power all the time via voltage divider.

If it is only for code development, you can ignore the Switch circuitry. A simple voltage divider should be fine.

[image]

---

[image]

**Simplest**

R1 and R2 are 80 kOhms and 15 kOhms respectively. For a max voltage of 6 V at Vin you will get 0.94 Volts at the ADC input pin (Vout). 
[image]

Comment: Okay so one way, is to use ADC pin to get battery voltage. The other way is to read VCC voltage as mentioned here : http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/reference.html but in order to do that ADC pin must be disconnected. Can I disconnect ADC by simply connecting it to ground? Or what is the easiest way to disconnect ADC ? Thank You!!

Comment: Disconnection means physically it should be floating..neither connected to ground nor connected to any other point.

Comment: If you want to only use built in function to read VCC, then just the leave ADC pin unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe zener diode could be used to remove excess voltage for A0 PIN.
Let say you have 4.2 voltage source and you want to monitor the one volt interval from 3.0 ... 4.0

So

`D1
(battery +)--[-|<-]--A0.`

If you take 3.0 V zener, it will leave the voltage interval 1.0...1.2 volts. The 1.0..1.2 probably at ESP will be read as 1023.

This will be more efficient as voltage divider will consume some current. In this case current level will be as small as ESP needs for readings. Only needs to test.. maybe it will be so small that zener won't turn on. Then maybe resistor would be needed to ground by from A0 contact point. Lets say some to consume some 100 microamp of 4.2 v, the resistor would be I=U/R; R=U/I (4.2/0.00001) = 42K.

`D1
(battery +)--[-|<-]--*-A0.
                     |
                    | |
                    | |  R1
                    |_|
                     |
                     _
                     -`

With zener you may get exact readings at ESP, you do not have hard code the coefficient voltage in source code.